# Crystal Report Error: query engine error 07009

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application, crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal report. There is an error while loading or retrieving data:

> `query engine error '07009: [ microsoft ] [ sql native client] invalid descriptor index'`

Comment: you need to give us more information about the report and the data queries it is running.

Answer (score 1):

some times crystel report is expecting column order. if its not you my be able to nail down the issue by checking the crystal error log file

you will be able to find the crystal report error log file in below path

```
c:\Windows\Crystal\SQLSvr.err
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same error and I found that it was because I had changed the data type on a couple columns in a table I was querying for the report. I verified the database and had to add the columns I had changed back to the report and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The report is expecting the order of the columns to be in a certain order, and its datasource isn't providing them in that same order.

See http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=871825 for more details.